# iOS ad-hoc app installed on device but cannot opem

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, ios-provisioning

I created an Ad-hoc build including the UDID of the device, but i cannot install or open app properly. Please help me out to find the cause for this

Thanks 
 [image]

Comment: There may be a lot of reasons for this - Like your manifest file doesn't have the same bundle id as your plist. Or there is some issue with your provisioning profile. can you elaborate the issue you are facing?

Comment: Have you follow the steps in this guide?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ad-hoc-distribution?tabs=windows

Comment: Yes, i have followed this step and app is getting successfully deploying on other devices which are registered in the developer account.